# OctoMap and octovis

Tags: ros, catkin-make, octomap, octovis

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS Indigo, and I am quite new to it. I need to use OctoMap: I installed everything from Debians (octomap, octovis etc..). MoveIt! can use the libraries and I can see the the OctoMap in Rviz, but I would like to process it and to select only a specific area of it, accessing the position of each voxel. For this, I guess I would need to use octovis or at least some of the .cpp contained in the octomap package, for seeing some examples on how to filter the map. The problem is that the package that I have under opt/ros/indigo/share is just an empty shell redirecting to the libraries: I see none of the files listed here (https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap), where it is full of examples and .cpp. How can I install/access those files?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256065/octomap-and-octovis/) by [HenrySleek](https://answers.ros.org/users/29535/henrysleek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2017-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In order to use a library (octomap) you do not need its source code. All required definitions are in the cpp-headers, which should be installed in /opt/ros/indigo/include. So in your code you can load the octomap and access it via all the methods provided by the library.

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2017-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1